# Нормативное употребление глаголов садитесь-присядьте

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правило: «Не следует говорить *присядьте*, следует говорить *садитесь*». 
А к слову *присаживайтесь* это тоже относится? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Тут два вопроса. 
Грамматический и этикетный.
По поводу грамматики. 
Глаголы сесть и садить(ся) хитрые. В каком-то смысле они образуют видовую пару (что сделать? - что делать?). Но при этом "садить" крайне редко используется в рассматриваем значении без приставки и возвратной частицы. 
В результате в приставочных вариантах получается необычная видовая пара (от разных основ и разной возвратности): присесть-присаживаться. Обе формы вполне нормативны. Повелительное наклонение - *присядьте* и *присаживайтесь* также грамматически правильны.

Но форма повелительно наклонения *присядьте* (от присесть) фонетически неудобна. Поэтому она обычно заменяется образованной от парной видовой (садитесь>*присаживайтесь*). Формы единственного сила это не касается: из пары "сядь и присядь" первая употребляется чаще.

Теперь об этикете. "Присесть", "присаживаться" обычно означает принять "положение на корточках" или "в присяде" (в спорте),  а также сеть ненадолго или на край чего либо, в неудобном положении. Так что использование и "присядьте" и "присаживайтесь" этикетно одинаково неправильно. Надо "садитесь" - если вы предлагаете гостю или даме сесть удобно и так, чтобы не вскочить через пять минут. Почему пошла мода говорить "присаживайтесь", сказать трудно. Есть версия, что связано с переносным значением "сесть" - оказаться в местах лишения свободы. И якобы на среди определенного контингента "садитесь" может быть воспринято неверно. Версия интересная, но не стопроцентно достоверная. Возможно просто от избыточного стремления к "изящной словесности".
(+)
Вообще есть незаслуженно забытое слово усаживайтесь (поудобнее). Оно может в неофициальной обстановке вполне примирить сторонников "садиться" и "присаживаться".

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, нормативное употребление глагола *садитесь*, а не присядьте и не *присаживайтесь*, связано всё-таки с точностью словоупотребления, с лексическим значением.

Сесть — принять сидячее положение — садитесь.

Присесть: 1. приседать; 2. сесть на короткое время.

Нужно просто употреблять слово в его истинном значении, не обращая внимания на суеверия (последний/крайний, сесть на стул/сесть в тюрьму). Если мы будем избегать нормальных слов, они уйдут из языка, останутся одни двусмысленности, уйдёт точность (как получилось с *класть*/*ложить*. Значение *ложить* от "ложе" уже забыто, а слово так и исчезло).

http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_6_krainij/