# "Садитесь", а не "присаживайтесь"

Tags: лексика, этикет

Корректным предложением занять какое-либо место является "Садитесь", а "присаживайтесь" имеет два значения, каждое из которых не может быть проявлением вежливости:

1. Сесть ненадолго;
2. Сесть на корточки.

Но "Садитесь" звучит грубее, как некое повеление, как проявление настойчивости, нетерпения.

Современные нормы относят употребление "присаживайтесь" в качестве "садитесь" к просторечным?

Comment: Пользуйтесь опцией Поиск: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415621/%d0%9d%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b5/415623#415623

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы **садитесь** не звучало грубее, необходимо добавлять "волшебное" слово **пожалуйста**. А если нужно подчеркнуть настойчивость, нетерпение и т. п., можно сказать **сядьте, пожалуйста** (заметьте, что даже в этом случае следует добавлять "пожалуйста", если нет желания подчеркнуть собственную невоспитанность или грубость).

> Современные нормы относят употребление "присаживайтесь" в качестве "садитесь" к просторечным?

В соответствии с современными нормами это употребление ошибочно, а не просторечно.

**Дополнение**.
Сошлюсь я тоже для солидности [на Грамоту](http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_6_krainij/). Только на главного редактора, а не на безымянных сотрудников. Там очень подробное объяснение и простой для понимания вывод:

> **Азбучная истина № 6.** Подойдя к очереди в кассу или к врачу в поликлинике, грамотно спросить у людей: *кто последний*? Предлагая гостю
> принять сидячее положение, вежливо сказать: *садитесь, пожалуйста*. А
> «кто крайний?» и «присаживайтесь» – это неправильно.

Comment: Просто так, для сведения: Юлий Бельчиков (один из авторов словаря, на который я ссылаюсь) — никак не безымянный сотрудник, а доктор филологических наук, автор нескольких книг, член научного совета РАН.

Comment: @Римма Согласен. Всё равно забавно, что Грамота даёт диаметрально противоречивые советы. Тогда опять поддержу Ваш ответ, с которым я не согласен :)

Comment: Знакомый автор, есть у меня его книга "Практическая стилистика современного русского языка", 2012 год., издание РАН. Я даже пыталась ею пользоваться, а потом обратила внимание, что текст похож на "Практическую стилистику" Розенталя, которого мы все здесь цитируем. Решила, что удобнее  пользоваться Розенталем. Я сейчас мне стало вот что любопытно.  Эти книги очень похожи, в том числе по делению на разделы, главы и по их названиям. А в предисловии о Розентале ни слова. Интересно, это нормально? Вот такой у нас доктор филологических наук.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, стоит отметить, что те значения, которые Вы приводите, относятся не к глаголу "присаживаться", а к глаголу ["присесть"](http://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Prisest-35232.html) (в повелительном наклонении — *присядь, присядьте*).

В словаре Ефремовой:
[**приса́живаться**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/227333/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), *несов.*

1. Садиться (обычно ненадолго, на короткое время).
2. Садиться возле кого-либо, чего-либо, рядом с кем-либо, чем-либо; подсаживаться.

Во-вторых, я бы не стала утверждать столь категорично: употребление слова "присаживайтесь" является ошибочным или просторечным.

Вот что разъясняет [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_66#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%2D%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%E2%80%93%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5,%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA.).

***Присаживаться и садиться***

**Вопрос**
Как правильно: *присаживайтесь* или *садитесь* при обращении к посетителю?

*Присаживаться — присесть* — сесть на короткое время или в недостаточно удобной, спокойной позе, в отличие от *садиться* (ср. также часто встречающееся *присаживайтесь поудобнее*).

Нейтральная форма при обращении к посетителю *садитесь*, но допустимо употреблять и форму *присаживайтесь*, хотя она имеет разговорный оттенок. Желание избежать формы *садитесь* объясняется, видимо, тем, что у глагола *садиться* есть и разговорное значение — «оказаться в заключении по приговору суда».

**Правильно**
при обращении к посетителю равноправные варианты — *садитесь* или *присаживайтесь*.

(Такая же информация имеется и в ["Словаре трудностей русского языка"](https://difficulties.academic.ru/149/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)).

Answer (score 1):

Словари словарями, а вы  сами-то как говорите или как у вас говорят – вот что интересно.

Приставка ПРИ в глаголе ***присесть*** обозначает или  расположение рядом с чем-либо (присесть к столу) или  имеет временное значение (присесть на короткое время).

**ПРИСЕСТЬ**,  св. 1. Опуститься на полусогнутых или согнутых ногах.  П. на корточки. Пёс присел на задние лапы. 2. Сесть на что-л., куда-л. (обычно на короткое время). П. отдохнуть. П. к столу. П. перед дальней дорогой, перед отъездом (старый русский обычай). П. на краешек стула. **Присаживаться,**  нсв. (2 зн.).

***Присаживайтесь***  не кажется мне нейтральным словом, у него обязательно присутствует какая-нибудь **коннотация**. В разных ситуациях это может быть:  или фамильярность и снисходительность;  или жеманность;  или выражение гостеприимства и избыточная вежливость (присаживайтесь, вот вам стаканчик, налейте себе водички).  Все эти значения определяют **разговорный стиль** слова.

**Вот вы приходите в какое-нибудь присутственное место** – на прием к руководителю фирмы или в частную клинику, где все вежливые и воспитанные. Нет,  секретарь вам не скажет – *присаживайтесь*.  Скорее это будет звучать так: *присядьте, пожалуйста,   вас скоро вызовут.*

**А гостей вы как приглашаете?** *Присаживайтесь, располагайтесь поудобнее?* А вдруг они подумают, что их здесь надолго не задерживают. Нет, уж лучше сказать так: *проходите, садитесь за стол, пожалуйста.*  Вежливо и без фамильярности.
*Присаживайся!*  А вот так можно обращаться только к близким друзьям, уж они-то не поймут вас неправильно.

В Интернете много статей на эту тему, где  слову дается **крайне отрицательная оценка,** например:

Вы никогда не замечали, что из повседневной речи практически исчезло вежливое обращение «садитесь»?

Отвратительное "присаживайтесь" вместо нормального "садитесь".

Сейчас вместо слова "садитесь" повсеместно употребляется "присаживайтесь". Дело в том, что у криминальных элементов имеется табу на употребление слова садитесь («Садиться можно в тюрьму», — утверждают они).

Предлагая присесть, вы предлагаете сесть на краешке стула или сесть ненадолго и быстренько уйти?

Тем не менее в Нацкорпусе  **400 примеров** со словом «присаживайтесь», так что оно  все-таки вошло в наш язык. Иногда кажется, что люди уже считают его нейтральным. Хорошо, что хотя бы **не все и не везде.**

Comment: Не вижу причин сокрушаться тем, что кто-то кое-где порой употребляет это обращение. Если я сам так не говорю, то просто потому, что не бываю в подходящих для этого ситуациях. Сейчас "присаживайтесь" ограничивается сферой делового общения, например, так можно сказать сотруднику, приглашенному на совещание из другого отдела, чтобы тот не стеснялся. Но в беллетристике разных времен есть и множество других, бытовых "гостевых" примеров; коллекция же "Корпуса" относительно скудна на любые слова и выражения.

Answer (score 0):

Для всякого слова - своя *ситуация* употребления, не всегда разумно браковать сами слова.
Вопрос интересен тем, что пробуждает вялотекущую дискуссию о праве на существование слова "присаживайтесь". Сеть завалена повторяющими одна другую статьями, приравнивающими это слово по неправильности употребления к слову "крайний" (вместо "последний") - даже "Грамота" не осталась в стороне. Направленная на разгром аргументация обычно держится на утверждении, что "присаживайтесь" побуждает адресата делать приседания,  будто "**присаживайтесь**" и "**приседайте**" - один и тот же императив. В словаре Ефремовой ничего подобного нет, вот значения слова "присаживаться":

> 1. Садиться (обычно **ненадолго**, на короткое время).
> 2. Садиться **возле кого-л.**, чего-л., рядом с кем-л., чем-л.;
>    подсаживаться.

В словаре Ушакова приводится такой пример:

> Монс **присаживался** за стол **к** доброй **компании**. (А.Н. Толстой.)

Здесь наглядно проявляется значение глагола: *сесть, **присоединившись** к кому-либо*.

Теперь по существу вопроса (употребление императива совершенного и несовершенного вида).

*Несовершенный вид* "**присаживайтесь**" (характерно словарное значение **2**).
Из приведенных значений глагола можно заключить, что  "присаживайтесь" - это вежливый призыв **сесть, присоединившись к собеседнику** для разговора, а не просто *занять сидячее положение*, - для этого есть другие вежливые формы обращения, например, к аудитории обращаются иначе: "**прошу садиться**", к старушке в транспорте - "**садитесь, пожалуйста**", а *требовательное* обращение "**сядьте**" употребляется в случае, когда кто-то встал со своего места, нарушив какой-нибудь регламент.

*Совершенный вид* "**присядьте**" (более характерно значение **1** - "*на короткое время*").
"Присядьте" может сказать начальник подчинённому, напр. вызванному "на ковер" для краткой нотации. В некоторых ситуациях такое обращение (как предложение сесть на короткое время) допустимо при общении хорошо знакомых людей - вспомним песенку: "*И если ты устал, то присядь, но не надолго!* "

Comment: Вся кампания по разгрому слова ориентируется на словарь Ефремовой, о приседаниях никто нигде не говорит.  Да и Монс сам присаживался/присоединялся к доброй компании, ведь его никто не приглашал:  присаживайся.  Разговор идет об этикете общения. А я-то думала у вас более строгие требования к правильной речи, чем где-либо еще, так что разочарована. Слащавое, неискренне или фамильярное словечко - таким я его слышу. Никогда так не говорю.

Comment: Я тоже так не говорю но это абсолютно ничего не значит. Это обращение можно встретить во множестве книг, включая такие как Словарь современного русского литературного языка, Изд-во Академии наук СССР, 1961, с.711 или Русский речевой этикет: лингвистический и методический аспекты (Н.И. Формановская, 1987). То, что слово даётся с пометкой "разг." отражает лишь факт его ненужности при письменном обращении, а не какую-то его ущербность.

Comment: Не устарели источники? Новый век – новые взгляды, новые слова. Надо перезагружаться.

Comment: Всё может быть, если "Грамота" уже всерьёз обсуждает вопрос о запятых вокруг предлога "в том числе", вставленного в качестве вводного слова :).

Comment: Это вредное влияние синкретизма,  а это плохое  слово, оно только кажется научным и красивым. СИНКРЕТИЗМ – нерасчлененность, характеризующая неразвитое состояние какого-либо явления. Есть еще ЭКЛЕКТИКА— соединение разнородных, внутренне не связанных и, возможно, несовместимых взглядов, идей, концепций.